# SMART support is available but goes back to Disabled on restart

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I've smartmontools installed on my ubuntu server.

HDD is smart capable:

```
sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda 



=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Scorpio Blue Serial ATA (Adv. Format)
Device Model:     WDC WD10TPVT-11U4RT1
Serial Number:    WD-WXC1A80P0314
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 20507d2dc
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Tue Sep 10 16:05:58 2013 GET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Disabled
```

I enable it by running:

```
sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda
```

If I run command smartctl -i again, I see SMART support is: Enabled. But this goes back to disabled on restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/rc.local` file with your favourite text editor, ie: `nano /etc/rc.local` and add the command to enable smart support before the last line of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

smartctl -s on /dev/sda 

exit 0
```

Save the changes with Ctrl+O and then Ctrl+X.

That script is runs on every boot so that would enable smart support for that disk on every boot.

Comment: Is this the recommended way of dealing with this issue?

Comment: Not sure, but it should work the way it is.

Comment: Or you can write your own script and use it on the right levels of init.d.